# Is it possible to install homebrew-ed and Enthought python on a Mac without interference with each other?

Tags: python, homebrew, enthought

I am a big fan of homebrew for package management on my Mac (OS X 10.6, x86_64).  However, I have been trying to install MayaVi and wxPython, etc., which has been a total nightmare.  Is it possible to install Enthought Python Distribution from their prebuilt binaries in a way that's not going to break my homebrew setup?

Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 2):

That should be no problem, as long as the PATH and the PYTHONPATH are set correctly.
I myself use the official newest Python distribution (2.7.x), the 32-bit EPD Python and the 64-bit Python in parallel and all I have to do is to quickly edit my .bash_profile to set the PATH appropriately.

There should be more clever methods out there to manage different versions efficiently, e.g. leave the PATH and PYTHONPATH untouched, but let them point to a soft link which you would change when you want to use a different Python (like the link in /Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/Versions/Current) but I prefer to quickly comment out the PATH definitions in my .bash_profile.

Another system to manage different setups is the python package [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Answer (score 2):

What K.-Michael Aye wrote seems to work. It took me a bit to understand (I'm a python and terminal noob) in case someone else is in that position here's some code:

Your `.bash_profile` tells your system what python package to use. It's located at `~/.bash_profile` and should look something like this with EPD python installed:

```
# Setting PATH for EPD-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export MKL_NUM_THREADS
```

Comment out the `PATH` and `export` lines. Restart terminal and check Homebrew:

```
$ brew doctor
Your system is raring to brew.
```

When you're done with the brew install, uncomment those lines and restart the terminal again to use the EPD python.

Answer (score 1):

I would also try python [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)- this would allow you to have your "default" environment with the homebrew goodness, and then when you want to use EPD run

```
python virtualenv.py EPD
```

You will probably have to uninstall/reinstall Enthought, which may have its own [challenges.](http://www.enthought.com/products/epdgetstart.php?platform=mac)
When I went down this path, I ended up abandoning EPD and went back to web based graphics with d3 (d3js.org) and its associated python library (https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py)